# Jquery-mobile is having issue in blackberry device

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry, jquery-mobile

I have a web app done for mobile platform using jquery-mobile. It works fine in android,iphone devices. But doesnt work on blackberry device. The whole page load at a time instead of loading a part of page. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For blackberry you didn't have that much of supported tags. I think Blackberry 7.0 Version **may** had this. Not only this but also you have to follow the blackberry web works rules like....

> It **doesn't** support the images names like **"load-image.png"**, it supports like **"load_image.png"**. Means not **"-"** must **"_"** for images. Not only for images **.html** or **.js** files etc;

I am giving one example. Like this you have to follow the some points;